# Semantic Ui react inline editing table

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I want to implement inline editing using semantic ui. I am trying to find solution. 
I found something, https://www.npmjs.com/package/sui-editable-table however, I am getting error as "can't resolve 'sui-editable-table'".

Any help would be appreciated?